# NumberFormatException in thread

Tags: java

Need some more help. Working on network chat programming from the cherno's tutorial series. I got to 24 and thats when things started going bad. I launched the server, I connected to it with a local client and connected to localhost, all that working fine. When I connect I get this error.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8474"
at     java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at com.josh.chat.ClientWindow$1.run(ClientWindow.java:78)
```

I set a random 4 digit number and I assign it as the ID here, and this is where the error applies to:

```
public void listen() {
listen =  new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        while(running) {                
            String message = client.receive();
            if(message.startsWith("/c/")) {
                message.trim();
                client.setID(Integer.parseInt(message.split("/c/|/e/")[1]));
                console("Successfully connected to server! ID: " + client.getID());
            }
        }               
    }

};
listen.start();
}
```

EDIT: added the whole function

The /c/ and /e/ SHOULD be working fine, I see no problems with them.

Comment: use a system out and check what value is coming here: `message.split("/c/|/e/")[1])`

Comment: You probably have non-printable characters in your string, so in addition to what *YoungHobbit* said, print the length of the string.

Comment: As a general comment: complex expressions like the one that you have inside the call `client.setIID` are hard to debug. Instead, introduce an "explanatory variable" that holds the output from `message.split`, and maybe another for the parsed client ID.

Comment: This may or may not b related, but your message.trim() call isn't doing anything - you need to assign it to the variable (the JavaDoc details that it returns a copy of the string which has been trimmed). To work on the trimmed version, you need "message = message.trim()"